# Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow. In python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack-overflow, python-3.7

I was trying to make my own terminal and when I was adding the feature to make your own functions and use them I got this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
```

**EDIT:**
For everyone looking for help with a similar error, this problem is caused by a function calling itself too many times. That causes an error because python is so far deep into running the function over and over and over again.

Comment: Post all errors and relevant code here directly as text as an [mcve].

Comment: You have an infinite loop. You have a `while True` with only one `break`. Obviously, the break statement is never being executed. Look at the conditions around the break statement and make sure they are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates that you have a function called `do` which calls itself, probably in an infinite loop.  When a function does that too many times (calls itself inside itself, which causes it to call itself inside itself inside itself...) you get what's called a "stack overflow".

If you don't do that, you won't get this error.